# Create array in GROUP BY

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am making a golf leaderboard in which I take all the hole scores from a specific matchid and group them by the userid. This part works just fine.

I do so like this:

```
$playersArray = array();

$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(point) AS points, COUNT(*) AS holes, COUNT(*)*2-SUM(point) AS topar FROM fb_score WHERE matchid=$matchid GROUP BY userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $playersArray[] = $row;
    }

}
```

Now, my question is, is there a waythat I can create an array of all the "point" for each user and get that into the $row?

Lets say that the SUM(point) is summed by lets say 3 points (3, 5, 4). Can I get this out in the result. As it is now I only get the latest $row for each user, but with the added "points", "holes" and "topar".

Hope this question makes sense :-/

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: $row['point'] is not what you want?

Comment: @user2078421 no that's the "last standing" match from the group by not the sum over all of the matches for each row.

Comment: @user2078421 I want to make $row[point] and array in the final result. Make sense? maybe create a new $row[pointsarray] = array(allpoints by user)

Comment: I think you need to do this in a separate query. In $playersArray[] you have the userid, so select all the points

Comment: It is because weirdly allowed syntax of `SELECT * ... GROUP BY userid`. Having an aggregation query, one can rely only on fields that are either aggregated, or listed in `GROUP BY` clause. Everything else covered by `*` should be treated as junk data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a bit hacky but it works. Simply GROUP_CONCAT the values and you get them in your $row var and you will be able to explode them in an array.

```
select *, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(point,CHAR)) as all_points from fb_score GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: Perfect... Works like a charm :-)